# Cayley graphs and the circulant graph $C_5(1,2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $n, m$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ be positive integers. An undirected graph with set of vertices $V=\{0, \ldots, n-1\}$ and set of edges $E=\left\{\left[i, i+a_j \bmod n\right]: 0 \leqslant i \leqslant n-1,1 \leqslant j \leqslant m\right\}$ is called a (symmetric) circulant graph, since the adjacency matrix of such a graph is usually called a circulant matrix, and it is denoted by $C_n\left(a_1, \ldots, a_m\right)$.

Forgetting the directions of edges, the circulant graph $C_5(1,2)$ is the Cayley graph of a finite abelian group $G$,where $G$ is isomorphic to the discrete torus $Z^2 / \Lambda_{(1,2)} Z^2$, with
$$
\Lambda_{(1,2)}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
5 & -2 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

I have three questions here:

1. why the group $G$ is isomorphic to the discrete torus $Z^2 / \Lambda_{(1,2)} Z^2$ and how to get it from the circulant graph $C_5(1,2)$.
2. Is there any algorithm to get the matrix $\Lambda$  from the circulant graphs$C_n\left(a_1, \ldots, a_m\right)$?
3. In general, How to calculate the quotient group $Z^2 / \Lambda Z^2$, where $ \Lambda $ is $2\times 2$ integer matrix?

Any help will be appreciated.